# Androidmainifest.xml being overwritten by new version after downgrade

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Hi I'm downgrading a project to Android 7.0, I've edited my build.gradle files but my mainifest.xml is being written over when I sync my project, this is causing problems as its writing a line which incorporates rounded icons. If not the build files then what could be overwriting my mainifest.xml file?

Comment: I solved my problem, the AndroidMainifest.xml that Android Studio displayed on the sync failing is located in \debug\ while I thought I was editing the AndroidMainifest.xml in app\main\. Simple issue but tricky if you don't realize you're editing a file that is influenced by another at build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 : close android studio 
 2 : go to the project directory 
 3 : find build.gradle and then open it with a TextEditor and then change the api level . 
 4 : then find mainifest.xml and open it with the same TextEditor and put the same api level in this file. 
 5 : open the android studio and check the problem again.